# Extend the column in primary table

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kustomize, kusto-explorer

I want to extend table 1 as IsAvailableInTable2 = Yes, if there's a value matching Id (Column in Table1) in column MonitorId in Table 2. I tried using materialize but didn't quite work out.

```
//Table 1
datatable(Id:string, MetadataKey:string, MetadataValue:string, Key:string, Value:string)
[
    "Restarting", "", "", "", "", 
    "Starting", "", "", "", "", 
    "Failed", "Location", "Monitor", "Routing", "xyz", 
]
```

```
//Table 2
datatable(MonitorId:string, Automitigated:long, AlertCount:long)
[
    "Restarting", 94, 94, 
    "Restart", 93, 93, 
    "Failed", 92, 92, 
]
```

Expected Result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHVz6.png)

Comment: could you please clarify why `IsAvailableTable2` appears as `No` in your expected result, if `Failed` appears in both `Table1\Id` and `Table2\MonitorId`?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
// creating the first table. optional, assuming the data is ingested, and not a 'datatable' literal
.set T1 <| datatable(Id:string, MetadataKey:string, MetadataValue:string, Key:string, Value:string)
[
    "Restarting", "", "", "", "", 
    "Starting", "", "", "", "", 
    "Failed", "Location", "Monitor", "Routing", "xyz", 
]


// creating the second table. optional, assuming the data is ingested, and not a 'datatable' literal
.set T2 <| datatable(MonitorId:string, Automitigated:long, AlertCount:long)
[
    "Restarting", 94, 94, 
    "Restart", 93, 93, 
    "Failed", 92, 92, 
]

// query
T1
| extend IsAvailableInTable2 = case(Id in ((T2 | project MonitorId)), "Yes", "No")
```

| Id | MetadataKey | MetadataValue | Key | Value | IsAvailableInTable2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Restarting |  |  |  |  | Yes |
| Starting |  |  |  |  | No |
| Failed | Location | Monitor | Routing | xyz | Yes |

Comment: Thank you , Yoni! If I have to project few columns from the Table2 in Table1, Will I need to do a join?

Also - Failed should be 'Yes'. It was a typo. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, using `join` would be suitable for that case